# How to detach shell from erlang process?

Tags: erlang, rebar3

I want to detach shell from erlang process without closing process. Does exist function like halt() or q() but for detaching shell? I tried to use Ctrl+D but it doesn't work, i use ssh maybe problem in that

--------Update --------------

I run my rebar3 release with command "bin/timeio start", sometimes i need to execute commands in that process from shell then I connecting to that process with rebar3 release command "bin/timeio attach" (it is simple erlang shell, I assume) but i can't detach from process

Comment: What process do you want to detach from? Provide an example what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Are you just trying to detach from the Erlang shell, while still having your program run?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean? how does the shell react?

Comment: Have you tried ctrl-g followed by q?

Comment: I don't know why but today Ctrl+D worked! I tried Ctrl+G+q but it kill process, thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CTRL-D should get you out and keep the app running. when you "attach" you are doing the same thing as running to_erl. To exit in from this you type control-D.,

```
 bin ⚑ ◒  → ./otto attach                                                                                                                                           master ✗ 83d
Attaching to /tmp/erl_pipes/otto@127.0.0.1/erlang.pipe.1 (^D to exit)

(otto@127.0.0.1)1> [Quit]
 bin ⚑ ◒  → ./otto attach                                                                                                                                           master ✗ 83d
Attaching to /tmp/erl_pipes/otto@127.0.0.1/erlang.pipe.1 (^D to exit)

(otto@127.0.0.1)1> [Quit]
 bin ⚑ ◒  → ./otto attach                                                                                                                                           master ✗ 83d
Attaching to /tmp/erl_pipes/otto@127.0.0.1/erlang.pipe.1 (^D to exit)

(otto@127.0.0.1)1> [Quit]
 bin ⚑ ◒  →                                                                                                                                                         master ✗ 83d
```